# Returning a HashMap in java

Tags: java, string, hashmap, return

I am currently new to Java coming from Python, and I can't seem to figure out how to return a HashMap, I tried searching on the web for hours but couldnt find anything that would solve my problem.
Here's the code.

```
public HashMap<Integer, Character> dataset(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char value = text.charAt(i);
        
        HashMap<Integer, Character> dict = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
        dict.put(i,  value);
        System.out.println(dict.getClass().getSimpleName());

        return dict; // Here's the error
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter text: ");
    String text = sc.next();
    
    System.out.println("============================");
    
    System.out.println("1. Convert to uppercase");
    System.out.println("2. Conver to lowercase");
    System.out.println("3. Convert to a dataset");
    System.out.print("Enter selection:  ");
    String choice = sc.next();
    
    StringConverter obj = new StringConverter();
    
    switch(choice) {
    case "1":
        text = obj.upperCase(text);
        System.out.println("=====Converted to uppercase=====");
        System.out.println(text);
        break;
        
        
    case "2":
        text = obj.lowerCase(text);
        System.out.println("=====Converted to lowercase=====");
        System.out.println(text);
        break;
        
    case "3":
        obj.dataset(text);

        break;
        
    }
}
```

I even double checked to see if the variable i am returning is a HashMap or not.

here's the exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
> This method must return a result of type HashMap<Integer,Character>

I know this might be a rookie mistake but after hours of research I couldnt find anything helpful.

Comment: You return from within a loop, and it's not allowed syntax to **only** return from a block, as your loop might not run at all. What if input argument's size is 0, for instance? return from method instead. Correspondingly, define your `dict` out of loop, at method level.

Comment: Do not run code that does not compile! The error message is clear: Your method `dataset` has to return something for each possible way. If `text.length()` is zero, then the loop does not run. What value shall be returned in that case?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri It is allowed to return from within a for-loop (although it is probably the wrong thing to do in this example, as is creating the map inside the loop). The problem is that the compiler isn't smart enough to evaluate the loop condition, so it also requires a return of something after the loop.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well, it is, as long as all the possible outcomes are considered. Compiler is smart enough to think, that the only possible variation of return here, is NOT ok for dynamic input, as that line may never execute. So, you have to code the method in a way, that disregarding of path execution may take, your method returns.. or throws exception. I think my comment mentions **only**.. although if it's vague a bit, I'll clarify it in this way: if **all the possible inputs** are covered, then you can return from any block of the method you wish; otherwise you risk *not* to return at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your definition of `dict` and your `return` statement out of the loop, and it should be fine (the first one before entering, the last one after exiting the loop).

In your current code, the `return` statement is not guaranteed to be reachable (i.e. if your loop is not even entered), which has to be given in a non-void function.

Additionally, your method would call `return` in each hypothetical iteration, which means your method will always end with the first iteration. A `return` leads to function exit, no matter what comes after, which means your code would not work as you'd expect. Additionally, you'd create multiple HashMaps, as you call the constructor once per iteration.

```
public HashMap<Integer, Character> dataset(String text) {

    HashMap<Integer, Character> dict = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char value = text.charAt(i);
        dict.put(i,  value);
        System.out.println(dict.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    return dict; // Here's the error
}
```

Comment: I genuinely can't believe I defined my variable inside a for loop and adding the return statement inside the loop also.